# Why are reputation changes not showing in the top bar?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, top-bar, live-refresh

Since some time in the last two or three weeks, upvotes do not show in the top bar the way they used to (like, `+10` on the achievements dropdown image for an answer upvote), at least on Super User. I have to click on the achievements dropdown image or go into my profile to see the recent reputation change. This was also network-wide, so it readily alerted me to voting going on on questions on other sites, sometimes causing me to revisit and improve them.

The reputation count (next to the avatar) is updated, but this is far from obvious.

I really miss reputation changes being somewhat prominently displayed. Where did that feature go?

**Edit:** It looks like this might affect only questions on sites *other* than the one I am currently browsing. Either way, an explanation of the intended behavior from someone in the know would certainly be appreciated! All the seemingly relevant posts I found were years old.

Comment: Something weird is *definitely* going on, but it might not be that outlined in my question. After I browsed onto MSE and posted this question, I seem to have started receiving those notifications, without having changed anything else.

Comment: Hmmm. Things are fine for me on all the sites I normally frequent. Could be something screwing up web sockets on your end? That said - what browser, OS are you on?

Comment: @Oded Environment is Iceweasel (rebranded Firefox) 31.5.0 on Debian Wheezy. One major weirdness here is that it seemingly *started working* after I browsed onto MSE.

Comment: Weird. Are they now working for you across the network?

Comment: @Oded It would appear that way. For the moment, this is status-norepro, but it definitely *was* a problem (and I was seeing it across browser restarts, and no recent relevant changes on my end that I can think of). Really, the only before/after change I can think of *is* that I browsed onto MSE, but I don't see how that should affect, say, Super User. It's not even under the same second-level domain.

Comment: For me the whole live refresh is not stable for several months. @Oded can't you see errors on the web sockets server on your side, maybe? Too much traffic, perhaps?

Comment: I agree with @Sha. It is working most of the times, but there are often outages too. A page refresh will sometimes help.

Comment: @Pat for me page refresh always help. E.g. when I leave browser open in MSE homepage and come back after hour, there's nothing in there - no "question with new activity" but after refresh they all appear. And rep changes as well - everything done via the sockets isn't there. Sometimes it works, most of the time for me, it doesn't.

Comment: @Sha same here. It is getting less stable than it was.

Comment: @Pat my guess is that with ever increasing user base and addition of new sites, the server is just overflowed with requests, so many are rejected. I assumed the team will notice and upgrade/put more servers, but looks like it's not the case. Let's hope it would be the case now.

Comment: @Sha let me close some open tabs... ;)

Comment: @Oded did you have change to look into this? I see more and more reports about live refresh being broken.