# Message for duplicates on Meta sites is incorrect

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, wording

On Meta sites we can close a question as a duplicate of another question which has no answers.

Which makes the current duplicate message incorrect:

> marked as duplicate by USER X hours ago
>
> This question has been asked before and **already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question**, please ask a new
>   question.

At the time of writing, [this (dupe) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261268/230506) is closed as a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260592/230506) which has no answers, but the close reason is as above (stating "already has answers").

---

This is for Meta sites only, main sites are different as you cannot close as duplicate if the supposed dupe question has no answers.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, The message is wrong, it states "already has answer" but the dupe *does not* have an answer. Is there something you did not understand? Something I've missed? Perhaps your cat mistook your shoes for it's litter tray this morning? Have a pleasant and delightful afternoon :)

Comment: Nah James, I'm pretty sure Tim lost his keys again. . .;) On another note, I think this could just be fixed by replacing that with "On meta sites, it's preferred to have discussions about a particular idea in just one post. Please post a bounty on that question if you want the community to pay attention to your request." Or something like that. . .I was never good at writing formal letters. :P

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Yeah something like that would be good :) I didn't suggest in this case as I don't care for something specific, just something *correct*

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I would not include the bounty information as meta.so does not have a bounty system.

Comment: @Nathan Well, if we are to write something separate for metas, we could as well isolate meta.SE. Don't worry too much about the details, as I believe with the surprisingly low count of votes on this question, this'll be addressed in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Let's see if that's true